# What does the NEL mean in in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to know, what the `NEL` does mean in Notepad++, and how to use a regex to find it in a whole txt file?

Please see the following picture to understand:

[image: NEL in notepad++]

Comment: It stands for [`Next Line Character`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia this is:

> NEL:   Next Line, U+0085

and its counted as one of the line terminators in Unicode.
Source [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: hah. All of those are newline methods - CR is carriage  return, and LF is line feed.

Answer (score 1):

To find it in Notepad++, open the Find window (Ctrl+F), enter `\x85` and make sure the *Search Mode* is set to *Extended*.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, they want to know the **meaning** of `NEL`

Comment: @Toto, they're also asking "how to use a regex to find it"..